# PHP - array limit

Tags: php, arrays, limit

```
$class = array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');

$people['c1'] = 'A';
$people['c2'] = 'B';
$people['c3'] = 'C';
$people['c4'] = 'D';

foreach ($class as $key)
{
  echo "Name: ".$people[$key]."\n"; 
}

result :

A
B
C
D
```

now when i add new 50 values to $class and $people

in some host everthing fine, but with hostpapa.com

looping only run well 36 time.

from 36+ , some values are null ( $people[$key] = null )

I don't know why. Maybe a settings limit the array ?

Note: Suhosin is instlled on this host

Comment: why didn't you ask hostpapa.com ?

Comment: You can't limit arrays in any normal version of PHP. Only memory limits apply, but I doubt that's a problem with 36 tiny strings.

Comment: Additionally, show us your code that "adds" 50 values and causes null values. It's more likely to be a typo.

Comment: @genesis: i'm waitting the anwser from hostpapa :D

Comment: @deceze: more clearly. some documention for this problem .

Comment: @Klyle Boddy: if a typo, while it run properly 50 time on another host ?

Comment: don't use c1 as a key, unless c1 is a defined constant. use 'c1'. Otherwise PHP checks if c1 is defined constant, then converts it to string 'c1', issuing a warning that c1 is not defined, which is written to logs and eventually outputed (depending on the settings). It's 4x slower.

Comment: @Darhazer: c1 is a example, i have unique id for key :)

Comment: @Chameron my point is, that if the id is a string, you have to use '' around the string :) Just a note, as this is a very common mistake.

Comment: @Darhazer: not with this case :)

Comment: can you post the values you added to $class and $people?

Comment: @rrapuya: above script is an example to explain my problem. In real script , adding values will be done by script , it's make sure no typo or wrong type variables :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the hosting company may be running the "security hardened" version of PHP known as [Suhoshin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/).

Suhoshin implements a large number of security hardening features for PHP, including the ability to limit stuff like field lengths and array sizes -- see http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html

It may be that something in your code is triggering one of Suhoshin's filters.

Either way, this sounds like something you need to discuss with your hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

```
$class = array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');

$people[c1] = 'A';
$people[c2] = 'B';
$people[c3] = 'C';
$people[c4] = 'D';

foreach ($class as $key)
{
  if(key() > 36) {
    break;
  }
  echo "Name: ".$people[$key]."\n";
```

I hadn't test this, but it's must work.
    }

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you do in for foreach statement it can be due to a limitation in execution time limit of you script.

If you do relatively timeconsuming stuff per loop in the foreach this could easily add up to minutes and this can run into the execution time limit in the php.ini.